# no login/no home dir user gets permission for denied (redhat8)

Tags: redhat, environment-variables

I am trying to solve a problem At work there is a given task where a python application is currently running on a server, this application is using a env file, which has username and password information. The current ask is to hide the  username and password string such that it's not available for regular users to see.

OS: redhat 8
application codebase: python3

so after few online discussion I have come up with following approach(please feel free to let me know if there is a better ad simple approach to solve this problem)

application is run by a dedicated user, say `nouser` I plan to have an environment variable which stores `db_password` and `test_nouser.py` can access these values when `test_nouser.py` is invoked to run.
to further harden, can we disable shell login for `nouser` such that no user can login as `nouser` have access to `db_password` ?

ok, now I created a user

```
#Add user with no home dir and no shell 


sudo adduser nouser --system --no-create-home --shell=/bin/false

#determine UID


id -u nouser
986
# created new file, /etc/profile.d/nouser.sh" [New File]


cat /etc/profile.d/nouser.sh
if [ "$(id -u)" -eq 986 ]; then
    export DB_PASSWORD = 'abcd1234'
fi

# create a test python file to see if this env variable exist for nouser
cat nouser_test.py
import os

print(os.environ)

#now when I try to access these env variables, I get permission denied

su -s /bin/sh nouser 'python3 nouser_test.py'
sh: python3 nouser_test.py: Permission denied
```

Comment: Why don't you just set the ownership and permissions?

Comment: Hi Can you elaborate a bit more ?

Comment: Ownership and permissions are very basic Linux concepts.

Comment: Sorry just checked, setting ownership won’t work in our case, as anyone who had admin access  will be able to read the .env file and reveal password

Comment: Who can have permission to access it, then?